# Dimension argument in the proof of Iversen's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am reading a proof of B. Iversen theorem that a non-constant polynomial $f$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ iff $\text{Ker}(F)=0$ and $\text{Ker}(F-I)=\mathbb{F}_p$ in *Concrete Abstract Algebra* textbook by Niels Lauritzen. (Here $F$ denotes the Frobenius map defined on $R=\mathbb{F}_p[X]/\langle f\rangle$.)

Proving the 'if'-part the textbook shows that given non-zero $a\in R$ the linear map $\varphi(x)=a x$ has $\text{Ker}(\varphi)\cap \text{Im}(\varphi)=0$. This I understand well enough.

But then it states that combining the bases of the kernel and the image of $\varphi$ as subspaces of $R$, we get a basis of the subspace $\text{Ker}(\varphi)+\text{Im}(\varphi)$ of $R$. And with this $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \text{Ker}(\varphi)+\text{Im}(\varphi)$ is equal to $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}R$ so that
$$
R=\text{Ker}(\varphi)+\text{Im}(\varphi)
$$
This is this dimension argument that I do not follow. I mean, how can we know that the dimensions are equal - I have no idea what the dimensions of $\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ and $\text{Im}(\varphi)$ should be in the first place. I suppose the degree of $R$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ must be $\deg(f)$, right?

Comment: What is $f$? Do you mean $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[X]$? Is $R = \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(f)$? What is $F$? Please provide some background, we cannot guess all the notations.

Comment: This question isn't serious: are we supposed to guess what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for that, I am trying to be serious! Martin Brandenburg pointed out that my question was not clear regarding the notation used. I hope it is clearer now!

Comment: It's clear enough IMHO. But I think a hard part is to prove that $\ker\phi\cap\operatorname{Im}\phi=0$. How did you get this? It doesn't hold for all $f$, for example $f(x)$ may have $a$ as a multiple factor. I guess we can use the assumptions about the kernels of $F$ and $F-I$ to deduce that?

Comment: But your question about the sum of the dimensions is just an application of the rank-nullity theorem. $\phi:R\to R$ is a linear mapping, so 
$$\dim \ker(\phi)+\dim\operatorname{Im}(\phi)=\dim R.$$ The sum of two subspaces of a vector space is direct, if they intersect trivially. In that case the dimension of the sum is the sum of dimensions, which is...

Comment: The $\text{Ker}(\varphi)\cap\text{Im}(\varphi)=0$ is explained like this: Given $x$ in the image we have $x=ay$ for some $y\in R$, given $x$ in the kernel we have $ax=0$. So for $x$ lying in both $a^2 y=0$. Thus $F(x)=a^p y^p=a^{p-2} y^{p-1}=0$ so $x\in\text{Ker}(F)=0$. Hence $x=0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jyrki Lahtonen! So this just displays my ignorance regarding Linear Algebra in the first year of my studies, right? I will have to have a closer look on the rank-nullity theorem then to make sure, I understand it now!!!

Comment: Ahh, yeah. Neat!

Comment: It is a bit surprising that anyone would study this before linear algebra ;-) BTW, are you from Aarhus?

Comment: Indeed very neat! I enjoyed that part - then came along Linear Algebra of which I have been to ignorant as I stated. How can I thank you when your answer appears to be a comment? I cannot vote for it then, can I?

Comment: I'll move it to an answer. Give me a minute.

Comment: Yes, I am from Aarhus. And as I wrote, I did study Linear Algebra back in the first year. But I found it a bit boring and technical. I prefer clever arguments about complicated things rather than technical methods of calculation. I have gotten quite familiar with applications of diagonalization for deducing closed forms of recursive relations since then. That is almost all I remember about Linear Algebra by now :(

Comment: Is Henning Haahr Andersen still at the Aarhus math department? I visited him in '91, but drifted to different kind of math later and lost track. I also visited Iversen's algebraic geometry seminar. He is a good lecturer, but IIRC was mildly annoyed about not being able to lecture in Danish because of me :-)

Comment: Yes, he is. He taught me analysis in my first year.

Comment: @YACP: Thanks for both your edits and comments! You are absolutely right that I mean the Frobenius map defined on $R=\mathbb{F}_p[X]/\langle f\rangle$. I will add this clarification right away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular question the OP had can be settled as follows. The ring $R$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the prime field $\mathbb{F}_p$. The mapping
$\phi$ is a linear transformation from $R$ to itself. Thus the rank-nullity theorem (sorry, I always forget its official name) states that
$$
\dim R=\dim\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)+\dim\operatorname{Im}(\phi).
$$
Both $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ are subspaces of $R$. As it was already proven that they intersect trivially, we know that their sum is direct. The dimension of a direct sum of vector spaces is the sum of the dimensions of the individual spaces, so in this case 
$$
\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)+\operatorname{Im}(\phi))=\dim R.
$$
As the sum $(\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)+\operatorname{Im}(\phi))$ is also a subspace of $R$, its dimension would be strictly less than that of $R$, if it were a proper subspace. The claim follows.

Comment: Thanks, both for your mathematical inputs and personal stories! Sorry for being so ignorant about Linear Algebra. I can see how I should really cath up on it some time soon! When I gain more reputation in here, I will vote for your answer. Right now the system will not allow me to. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I am slightly getting the hang of this forum now. I checkmarked your answer and voted for it as well. Also I tried answering a question myself. It is just brilliant how you can exchange perfectly formatted math in this way!!!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, @String. Yes, this is a cool site.