# Uniqueness of complements in general vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

### Motivation

I asked the question: [Is my proof correct: rank-nullity in a field $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495244/is-my-proof-correct-rank-nullity-in-a-field-k). Although the answer given by *Marc van Leeuwen* made perfect sense, it made me wonder about one thing:

### Introduction

We are given a field $K$ and a linear map $\varphi$ from $K^n$ to $K^m$. Then we choose a basis for $\text{Im}(\varphi)$, and for every $w_i$ in that basis a vector $v_i$ in the pre-image of $w_i$. Then we define a linear map $g:\text{Im}(\varphi)\rightarrow K^n$ so that $g(w_i)=v_i$ and deduce that $\text{Ker}(\varphi)\cap\text{Im}(g)=\{0\}$ since $\varphi(x)=0$ implies $x=g(\varphi(x))=0$. Furthermore each element in $x\in K^n$ can be expressed as
$$
x=[x-g(\varphi(x))]+g(\varphi(x))
$$
where the expression in the brackets is in $\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ and the last term is in $\text{Im}(g)$. So we see how $K^n=\text{Ker}(\varphi)\oplus\text{Im}(g)$. So $\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ and $\text{Im}(g)$ are complements.

### Question

Now what puzzles me is, that whereas $\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi$, the image $\text{Im}(g)$ seems NOT to be as it depends on $g$ that again depends on the choice of $v_i$. If there exists a non-zero element $r\in\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ we could choose $v_i+r$ as elements in the pre-image $\varphi^{-1}\left(\text{Im}(\varphi)\right)$ that would then form a basis for a linear map $h:\text{Im}(\varphi)\rightarrow K^n$ and by the exact same arguments as before obtain $K^n=\text{Ker}(\varphi)\oplus\text{Im}(h)$. But each $v_i+r\in\text{Im}(h)$ is NOT an element of $\text{Im}(g)$ because of the non-zero element $r\in\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ and the fact that $\text{Ker}(\varphi)$ and $\text{Im}(g)$ intersect trivially. So we have
$$
K^n=\text{Ker}(\varphi)\oplus\text{Im}(g)=K^n=\text{Ker}(\varphi)\oplus\text{Im}(h)
$$
but $\text{Im}(g)\neq\text{Im}(h)$. This seems contradictory to me, or at least contra-intuitive. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice this question before. The non-uniqueness of complements is exactly why my proof was set-up in the somewhat curious way it is. To define a situation where rank-nullity is related to a direct sum situation, one needs to choose a complement to the kernel, which choice was disguised in the choice of a linear map $g$ in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us think about the plane $\mathbb R^2$. Let $U$ be the $x$-axis, and $V \neq W$ be two non-horizontal lines of the plane. Then you have $\mathbb R^2 = U \oplus V = U \oplus W$, because you can think of direct sum as translation along all the vectors of $V$ or $W$ in this case. Hence we are in the same case as the one you described, and maybe this one is easier to visualize.

Note however that you'll always have $V \simeq \mathbb R^2/U \simeq W$, hence although the spaces $V$ and $W$ are not *the same*, they *look like* exactly the same.

Comment: Ok, I get the picture: so it is just my intuition that needs to be adjusted! Since we are talking about complements, not orthogonal complements, they need not be uniquely determined but can still form direct sums.