# Help me with this theorem about matrix representation of a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

**Theorem:** Let $V$ and $W$ be both finite dimensional vectorspaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map. Then there exists a basis in $V$ and a basis in $W$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases is of the form: \begin{align*} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{I}_r & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\end{align*} where $r$ is the rank of the linear map.

Can anyone explain me why this is so?

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know what it has to do with this being the matrixrepresentation of the particular linear map.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Consider the matrix $(1 1;0 1)$. This matrix should then be $I$ by your theorem

Comment: Take any representative matrix $A$ for $T$. Then find a basis $\mathcal B$ for $Col(A)$. Then perform the change of basis $\mathcal B \ni b_i \mapsto e_i$

Answer (score 3):

For a straightforward proof, one can start to choose a basis for the kernel of$~T$. But since this needs to be the final part of the basis used in $V$, let $n=\dim V$ and $r=n-\dim(\ker(T))$ (this is the rank of $T$, but I want to avoid using rank-nullity here), and take $v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n$ to be a basis of $\ker(T)$. Extend by $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ to a basis of$~V$ (incomplete basis theorem). Put $w_i=T(v_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq r$. Now $w_1,\ldots,w_r$ are linearly independent: if $c_1w_1+\cdots+c_rw_r=0$ then $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_rv_r\in\ker(T)$, whence that linear combination is also a linear combination of $v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n$; since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$ and $\{v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ are disjoint parts of a same basis, this is only possible if all coefficients are$~0$, so $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_r=0$. Finally this allows the incomplete basis theorem to be applied again to extend $w_1,\ldots,w_r$ to a basis of $W$, and with respect to the bases so chosen it is clear that the matrix of$~T$ has the form indicated in the question.

---

For those who find the proof of the linear independence of $w_1,\ldots,w_r$ too tedious, there is also a [more slick approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/495275/18880) that starts by choosing $w_1,\ldots,w_r$ as a basis of the image of$~T$ and then $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ as pre-images under$~T$ of those vectors; the linear independence of the latter is now easy, by applying$~T$. However, it must now be checked that the span of those pre-images is a complementary subspace to$~\ker T$, so that it is possible to complete with $v_{r+1},\ldots,v_n$ forming a basis of $\ker(T)$. Which approach is easier is a matter of taste.

Comment: slick approach refers back to one of your answers. is that not what i did in my answer?

Comment: It is. But you did not provide a (complete) proof. Also, it does not suffice to just extend $v_1,\ldots,v_r$ to a basis of $V$, one must do that using vectors of $\ker(T)$. And to prove that this is possible, you must prove that the span of the $v_i$ form a complement of $\ker(T)$. In other words there remains some things to do.

Comment: op asked for an example and i gave one. you are making it more complicated than it needs to be. if you find a logical error in my explanation that would be different.

Comment: I already indicated a logical error in my previous comment. Also OP asked "is this always true?"

Answer (score 2):

let the dimension of $V, W$ be $n, m.$ since the dimension of the image of $T$ is $r$ let $\{w_1, w_2, \cdots w_r \}$ be a basis for the image of $T.$
now expand this $\{w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_m\}.$ also define $v_1, v_2, \cdots v_r$ so that $Tv_1 = w_1, Tv_2 = w_2, \cdots Tv_r = w_r.$ first verify that $\{v_1, v_2, \cdots v_r\}$ is linearly independent and then extend to $\{v_1, v_2, \cdots v_n\}$ a basis of $V$ in such a way that $\{v_{r+1}, \cdots, v_n\}$ is in the null space of $T.$

the transformation $T$ with respect to 
 $\{v_1, v_2, \cdots v_n\}$ and $\{w_1, w_2, \cdots, w_m\}$  is the matrix $\pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0&0}.$

here is an example from your comment. suppose $n = 2, m = 3, T\pmatrix{a_1, a_2} = \pmatrix{a_1 + 3a_2\\0\\2a_1 - 4a_2}.$  choose the basis $\left\{\pmatrix{1\\0\\2},  \pmatrix{3\\0\\-4}, \pmatrix{0\\1\\0} \right\}$ for $R^3$ and the standard basis 
$\left\{ \pmatrix{1\\0}, \pmatrix{0\\1} \right\}$ with respect to these basis $T$ has the matrix representation $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1\\0&0}.$

Comment: Can you give an example? And is this always true? Doesn't the theorem depend on the linear map? For example, if I have a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the transformation is defined as $T(a_1,a_2)=(a_1+3a_2,0,2a_1-4a_2)$. If $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are standard ordered bases for these spaces, how could that work?

Comment: "then extend to $\{v_1, v_2, \cdots v_n\}$ a basis of $V.$" This is not good enough. The final columns of your matrix will just be linearly dependent on the previous ones, but not necessarily zero.

Comment: not good enough for what? that it cannot be done?

Comment: Not good enough to get a matrix of the form given in the question. I think my comment previous already indicates this; please try to read my comments as carefully as I try to formulate them.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen,  i see now what you meant. i have qualified the extension of the basis.